# How Can Get Back to Chrome version of Salesforce 1 on iPad from Classic View?

Tags: salesforce1-app, chrome, ipad, classic

Nonprofit I work for has recently gone paperless with iPads for our client intake. Started out using Salesforce 1 app, but it is unstable and often crashes, freezes, or gets stuck in a loop on a contact despite searching for other contacts. So we started using Chrome which is much more stable and seemed to intuitively bring up a similar "version" of the app. A few weeks in I launched the Classic view on the iPad for some volunteers who know their way around, but now that I have done that, the iPad will only launch the Classic view in Chrome. When I hit the Go to Salesforce 1 link at the bottom of the Classic view it launches the app, which I don't want. I deleted the app, but chrome still just pulls up the big blue landing page to indicate the app. I deleted browser history, etc. in chrome, but same landing page. I changed the URL, but it just redirects me back to the same page. How can I get back to the Chrome app version of Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Use the switcher to toggle back:

> Now, click your name in the upper right corner. You should now see Switch to Lightning Experience in the menu. If you don’t see the Switcher, ask your admin for help. You might not have the option to switch to Salesforce Classic. This feature is called the Switcher. It allows each user to switch back and forth between Lightning Experience and the previous user experience, Salesforce Classic, on demand. Let’s practice that now.
>
> Click on your name and select Switch to Lightning Experience.

**References**

- [Enable Lightning Experience Unit | Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/quickstart-lightning-experience-sales/steps/qs-lex-sales-1)
- [Make Your Classic App Available in Lightning Experience Unit |](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/migrate-a-classic-app-to-lightning-experience-with-declarative-tools/steps/make-your-classic-app-available-in-lightning-experience)